# Python Eve contains filter

Tags: python, rest, flask, eve

There's some way to return items that field contains some value? Eg.

`GET /people?contains="foo"`

Return all persons that have the word 'foo' in the name.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use mongodb `$regex` operator, which is blacklisted by default in Eve (`MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST = ['$where', '$regex']`).

Add `MONGO_QUERY_BLACKLIST = ['$where']` to your `settings.py`. Then you can query your API like this:

`?where={"name": {"$regex": ".*foo.*"}}`.

Be careful however. If you don't control the client, enabling regexes could potentially increase your API vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But what I really need is the $text operator (fulltext search). I think this is was not implemented yet, I'll fork and sent a pull request soon

Comment: @Skhaz , how did the work with the $text operator go?

Comment: Could this also be done by defining an 'additional_lookup' for the schema in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

I am not conversant with Eve myself. But looking at it's webpage seems like it exposes all of Flask's functionalities.

You need to be looking at [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#accessing-request-data) page in the documentation that talks about accessing the request data.

In your Flask app, define a method that accepts both POST and GET requests and then you can access `foo` by doing `request.args.get('contains', '')`.

This is what I mean:

```
@app.route('/people', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def get_people():
    search_key = request.args.get('contains', '')
    #search for people containing 'foo' in your DB
```

Hope this gives you a starting point as to how to go about things.

Comment: I was thinking in something more "automatic". Thanks for your reply!