# Use "like" operator and OR clause

Tags: eve

I've been searching a solution for my problem, but I didn't find an answer.
I have this data in my database

```
{
  "_items": [
    {
      "_id": "5a69bbbe085eb50006b7515b",
      "sku": "SAB-EM",
      "name": "Sabão em pó",
      "price": 12,
      "promotions": [],
      "_updated": "2018-01-25T11:13:02.000000Z",
      "_created": "2018-01-25T11:13:02.000000Z",
      "_etag": "49fda82778b967e008ba46f7600822e940abb92b",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "title": "Product",
          "href": "products/5a69bbbe085eb50006b7515b"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a69bbc7085eb50006b7515c",
      "sku": "AMA",
      "name": "Amaciante",
      "price": 15,
      "promotions": [
        {
          "bundle_quantity": 10,
          "paid_quantity": 8,
          "_cls": "QuantityBundlePromotion"
        },
        {
          "bundle_quantity": 3,
          "paid_quantity": 2,
          "_cls": "QuantityBundlePromotion"
        }
      ],
      "_updated": "2018-01-25T11:13:11.000000Z",
      "_created": "2018-01-25T11:13:11.000000Z",
      "_etag": "2308eb7c8c597ee441229d593a545e7e61a30160",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "title": "Product",
          "href": "products/5a69bbc7085eb50006b7515c"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "5a69bbca085eb50006b7515d",
      "sku": "DET",
      "name": "Detergente",
      "price": 2,
      "promotions": [
        {
          "minimum_quantity": 5,
          "discount_percentage": 0.15,
          "_cls": "DiscountForMinimumQuantityPromotion"
        }
      ],
      "_updated": "2018-01-25T11:13:14.000000Z",
      "_created": "2018-01-25T11:13:14.000000Z",
      "_etag": "73583c72a90bc8b89e30d9b7ab5b904cd78827a1",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "title": "Product",
          "href": "products/5a69bbca085eb50006b7515d"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "parent": {
      "title": "home",
      "href": "/"
    },
    "self": {
      "title": "products",
      "href": "products?max_results=3"
    },
    "next": {
      "title": "next page",
      "href": "products?max_results=3&page=2"
    },
    "last": {
      "title": "last page",
      "href": "products?max_results=3&page=29"
    }
  },
  "_meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "max_results": 3,
    "total": 87
  }
}
```

When I search using http://0.0.0.0:3000/products, that is the result.
there is my question, I need to search this by **name** or **sku** using **like** operator. But I've looked everywhere and found nothing, I've tried using MongoDB format but it returns 400.

When I run [http://0.0.0.0:3000/products?where=name=="SAB-EM" or sku=="SAB-EM"](http://#) it returns something, but I still need to execute this using **like** operator, not literal.

PS: I don't have access to python-eve configuration.

Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to escape your query. Try something like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/regions?where=name==SAB-EM%20or%20sku==es
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem, so others will know that this is a valid solution.

Comment: this is already working, I really need to use the like LIKE operator, but I didn't found how to make this.

SQL Query Example
Select * from products where name like("SAB%") or sku like ("SAB%")

Comment: Oh I see. Then see if this answer helps (but you will most likely need access to eve configuration in order to remove regexes from the blacklist): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097154/python-eve-contains-filter/23102713#23102713

Comment: I have tried this, not working. that result is a test, they have developed the back-end and the eve server, I can only access data. 
Tks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

i know that this question is old, but:
If you are using python-eve with SQL (sqlalchemy) the statements'or' and 'and' with 'like' is:

```
/resource?where={"or_": [
                             {"my_column1": "like(\"%value%\")"},
                             {"my_column2": "like(\"%value%\")"}
                        ]
                 }
```

to use 'and' statement just replace "or_" to "and_"